# CPU frequency goes back after scaling down by indicator-cpufreq, suspension and waking up

Tags: ubuntu, cpu-frequency

I scale down the CPU frequency by indicator-cpufreq on Ubuntu 12.04.

After I suspend Ubuntu and wake it up, the CPU goes back to"on demand" (the default). I wonder if there is a way to keep the CPU frequency after scaling it?

**NOTE:** sometimes, my Ubuntu can't wake up completely, and my laptop can easily become overheated under CPU frequency on demand.